# Поддерживаются ли символы _ в названии хидера http запроса?

Tags: http

Меня интересует можно ли использовать в кастомных `http` хидерах (названиях полей) символ `_`?

Comment: Да блин, за что минус то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ `_` использовать разрешено, он соответствует стандарту:

> The  field-name must be composed of printable ASCII characters
> (i.e., characters that  have  values  between  33.  and  126.,
> decimal, except colon)

[rfc822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.1)

Но Nginx пропускает заголовки с символом `_`, если специально не включить опцию [underscores_in_headers](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/?highlight=disappearing%20http%20headers#missing-disappearing-http-headers):

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

Добавим эту опцию и создадим файл для проверки `headers.php`:

```php
<?php
var_export(getallheaders());
```

Проверим:

```
curl -sS 'http://localhost:8200/headers.php' -H '_Header: value'

# Ответ:  
array (
  '_header' => 'value',
  'Accept' => '*/*',
  'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.61.0',
  'Host' => 'localhost:8200',
  'Content-Length' => '',
  'Content-Type' => '',
)
```